# Vue Form component in Laravel getting 422 error on submission

Tags: laravel, forms, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to add a Vue form component to my Laravel application so I can reuse it in a few places throughout the app. But when I submit the form I get a 422 error saying that the route is not found.

Form component:

```html
<template>
<form @submit.prevent="mail" method="POST">

</form>
</template>
<script>
import FormMixin from '../FormMixin';

export default {
  mixins: [ FormMixin ],
  data() {
    return {
      'action': 'submit',
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Form Mixin

```html
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fields: {},
      errors: {},
      success: false,
      loaded: true,
      action: '',
    }
  },

  methods: {

    mail() {
      if (this.loaded) {
        this.loaded = false;
        this.success = false;
        this.errors = {};
        axios.post(this.action, this.fields).then(response => {
          this.fields = {}; //Clear input fields.
          this.loaded = true;
          this.success = true;
        }).catch(error => {
          this.loaded = true;
          if (error.response.status === 422) {
            this.errors = error.response.data.errors || {};
          }
        });
      }
    },

  },
}
```

Controller

```html
 public function mail(NewConctactRequest $contact) {
     
     Mail::to('example@example.com')->send(new NewContact($contact));

     return redirect()->route('thank you');

     return response()->json(null, 200);

    }
```

Web Routes

```html
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('adventures', 'PageController@adventures')->name('adventures');
Route::get('crew', 'PageController@crew')->name('crew');
Route::get('events', 'PageController@events')->name('events');
Route::get('gallery', 'PageController@gallery')->name('gallery');
Route::get('thank_you', 'PageController@thank_you')->name('thank you');
Route::get('contact', 'ContactController@show')->name('contact');
Route::post('submit', 'ContactController@mail')->name('mail contact');
```

I have Axios installed already and the CSRF token is set in the head pf the document. When I use the form as just a standard form (not using Vue) it submits properly.

Comment: The 422 response code usually means that there's a validation error occurred. Please check the content of `NewConctactRequest` class and add it to your post if you want it to be reviewed. The class is probably located in `app/Http/Requests` catalog.

Comment: @OleksandrKovpashko that was it. I forgot to check the validation in the NewConactRequest. Once I commented out what I was not using it worked. Thank you,

Comment: @OleksandrKovpashko I have one more question, how do I get my redirect to work properly now?  All that is happening is my form is cleared and  I want it to go to a new page. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, you should get rid of two consequent `return` statements from the controller's action. Just leave the second one.
Then for ajax form submissions you must do redirects manually in your JS code.

Comment: @OleksandrKovpashko I actually just rolled everything back to just using Laravel to handle everything. I have not really worked with Vue.js before so I am not very familiar with how that frame works.

Comment: I understand. It's not how Vue.js works. It's a different paradigm when you send the data to the server without the full page reloading. You don't request a new document from the server so the returned from the API redirect has no effect.